# Can we assign Primary key in JPA as ABC0001, ABC0002, ABC0003.... so on?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, derby

I am using `Ecliplink 2.5` and `Derby 10.10.1.1`. I want to assign the primary key such that it generates in the sequence defined above.

Is it possible to do so?

One method I was able to think was to create a composite key which includes one constant as ABC and another numeric starting as "0001"(which could be defined in sequence generator).

But I am more of a looking towards a approach where I only need to define it as a whole and not a composite key.

Comment: don't have experience with EclipseLink, but quick google shows that custom generator is not very hard to implement (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/CustomSequencing). I'd personally go with a "IDENTITY" GeneratedValue and an insert trigger to generate value on derby via procedure.

Comment: I think your request is at odds with general database schema design principles. In general, the whole point of a synthetic primary key is that it should have no meaning to your program; its only property is that it uniquely identifies your record. If you need a key which has meaningful values for your program, you should generate those values yourself.

Comment: As Uiron mentioned, you will need to use a custom sequence class to append the 'ABC' string.  If you don't want to handle the sequence entirely, then you can use NativeSequence or TableSequence within your custom sequence object to handle  the numeric sequence for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `Trigger`. Write a trigger on your `derby` for the table which will execute before insert(I don't know what it calls in derby). Inside the trigger you can fetch the `001` from a sequence or from another table if you wish. And you can customize the `ABC` with hard coded, or using another table(if you plan to use XYZ, PRQ, etc too). This is just the basic concept, main thing is you can do it using Trigger easily.